# JavaScript- how to print p element inside div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I Know I can do this with static HTML, but I want to create dynamically, and I am struggling a lot.
Here is what I want to do: 
I have 2 divs.

```
    <div class="TxtTile">

    </div>
    <div class="pInfo">

    </div>
```

Inside each div I want to have several paragraphs. Let's say 10, in each div. 
The first div with class `"TxtTile"` i want to have the title of something, let's say titles like, age,country,experience,street etc.In the other div with class  `'pInfo'` I want to contain the information that corresponds with TxTtitle. 
Like, age  25, experience 10 years etc, that will be taken from local Storage, where I already have it set up. This two divs will be next to each other, which I have already done with css.

For example. 
Left side

```
<div class="TxtTile">               `<div class="pInfo">

 <p class="styleforP">                   <p class="styleforP">
    Age                                      25
                                         </p>
 </p>

</div>                                </div>`
```

I would be happy if I can make this with native js.

Comment: [`<table>`](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp) might be a good solution for this requirement.

Comment: Using tables for layout is never a good solution. Tables should be purely for tabular data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this:

**1) you can create an element and keep appending to its place**

First get div element inside which you want to create new element, Here rather than having a class i would prefer to have id based selection of the element

```
var element = document.querySelector('.TxtTile');
```

Create a `p` element and add class to it, you can similarly add content inside it aswell

```
var pElem = document.createElement('p');
pElem.className = 'styleforP';
pElem.innerHTML = 'Age';
```

Append that created element inside your div

```
element.appendChild(pElem);
```

**2) Create an HTML template pass your values to that template and create innerHTML and directly put that innerHTML into your parent element**

```
var item = {
    name: "My Name",
    age: 30,
    other: "Other Info"
}
var template = [];

template.push(
    '<div class="row">',
        '<span class="name-info">' + item.name + '</span>',
        '<span class="age-info">' + item.age + '</span>',
        '<span class="other-info">' + item.other + '</span>',
    '</div>'
);

var htmlString = template.join('');
var element = document.querySelector('.TxtTile');
element.innerHTML = htmlString;
```

If you are going to add a lot of items then second approach is a lot better, as creating single element and appending them to DOM tree is quite slow, then passing whole HTML string.

Comment: I like this approach. But, i need multiple p elements inside  TxtTile with different  values, like first is age, then is country etc, i would need 10. So do i need to write 10 times like that?

Comment: @Bokchee88: There are two ways you can do this 1) you can create an element and keep appending to its place 2) Create an HTML template pass your values to that template and create innerHTML and directly put that innerHTML into your parent element

Answer (score 2):

```js
var myData = {
  title: "My title",
  info: 25
};

// Store references to the wrapper elements

// The first element that has this class, or null if there aren't any
var titleWrapper = document.querySelector(".js-titleWrapper"); 
var infoWrapper = document.querySelector(".js-infoWrapper");

// Create the paragraph elements
var titleP = document.createElement("p");
var infoP = document.createElement("p");

// Add classes
titleP.classList.add("styleForP");
infoP.classList.add("styleForP");

// Add the text
titleP.innerText = myData.title;
infoP.innerText = myData.info;

// Add the paragraphs to their wrappers
titleWrapper.appendChild(titleP);
infoWrapper.appendChild(infoP);
```

```html
<div class="TxtTile js-titleWrapper">
</div>

<div class="pInfo js-infoWrapper">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this is a bad idea for doing this if you have multiple records then you cant handle by querySlector.

good idea is create a parent element like this

```
<div id="parent"></div>
```

then get this element by javascript and then append this element with your dynamic records like this

```
var parentEle = document.getElementById("parent");
```

apply loop if records are multiple

```
var child = Document.createElement("div");
child.innerHTML = "<div class='TxtTile'>age</div><div class='pInfo'>25</div>";
parentEle.appendChild(child);
```